# Oscillating frequency of a perturbed arc on the ground

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory, rigid-body-dynamics

This problem happens to me today. The illustration below is quite self-explanatory. Assume that there is no sliding, only rolling. Given an initial tilt, the arc will oscillate around the equilibrium position. I am interested in its frequency $f$. If possible, a large amplitude solution of $f$ depending on the oscillating amplitude is also welcomed.
[image: illustration]

It looks like a typical problem in classical mechanics, which I haven't touched for years. By dimensional argument $f$ depends on arc radius $R$ and gravitational constant $g$, but this does not lead to an exact coefficient. I don't know how to write down an equation, as the moving point of contact puzzles me a lot. To me it is very different from the SHO.

A direct extension of this problem is to 3D, where a fraction of a sphere shell tumbling on the ground plane---imagine a piece of a broken bowl. Those motions seem quite interesting, so I would be happy to learn about the exact, classical solutions. Any thoughts or references are welcomed.

Comment: A discussion of a similar problem here https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/oscillation-of-a-solid-hemisphere.735271/

Comment: If you are only interested in the period and not the detailed equation of motion, I remember that you can get this from the energy surface and the according turning points. If only I had my old mechanics book at hand (Just can't find the according formula in internet).